# "Possibly unhandled rejection: ZERO_RESULTS" angular 1.6.6 ng-map Geocode ui-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

I have been struggling trying to solve `Possibly unhandled rejection: ZERO_RESULTS`-messages that I get when closing a ui bootstrap modal with a ng-map inside of it. There is two of the same entry.

Here is an image of the errormessages:
[Error message from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qo7N.png)

From what I have gathered it is exactly what it says.. An unhandled rejection. I have went through all promises I use in my controller and all of them have a `.catch()`-block. This has led me to belive that the error is from a thirdparty plugin.

This is the markup for ng-map:

```
<div map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js" 
     map-lazy-load-params="{{map.apiKey}}" lazy-init="true">
    <ng-map zoom="14" center="{{map.coordinates.x}},{{map.coordinates.y}}">
        <marker position="{{map.coordinates.x}},{{map.coordinates.y}}">
        </marker>
    </ng-map>
</div>
```

I removed the `<marker>` and one of the error messages goes away. If I remove the `<ng-map>` aswell the other message is gone, however that means that the map and the marker are gone.

**NOTE:** Hiding the error message is NOT an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify fake coodrinates for `map.coordinates.x` and `map.coordinates.y` on `marker` and `ng-map` directives. Properties `position` and `center` need a valid numbers and if they are not provided angular throws an error. This is the best i came with.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you missed to catch blocks somewhere. Go through your code and add catch() blocks to all promises.

Comment: Every promise in my controller has a catch block. But maybe I can try to catch the error higher up, and handle it there.. I will try and come back!